# Setting the height of the TabWidget on Android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I'm making an Android app that has a TabWidget along the bottom of the screen.

I want the tabs to all be 77px (or, dp, I suppose) high.  To do this, I've added the following lines of code:

```
<FrameLayout
        ...
        android:layout_height="77dp"
         />
<TabWidget
        ...
        android:layout_height="77dp"
         />
```

This elevates the tabs above their original position, however, rather than the tabs actually getting taller, there's simply white space added beneath the tabs.  [Here is a screenshot to show what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTI8r.png).

Does anyone know how to increase the height of an Android tab widget / tabs themselves?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the entire layout?  I'm curious to see what you did to get the tabs to align at the bottom.  Try using the padding top and bottom to see if that helps.

android:paddingTop="39dp" 
android:paddingBotom="38dp"

if this doesn't help please post your entire layout.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It seems like adding padding to the top and bottom only creates more white space, however. Here's the source of the entire XML file.  I believe it's "layout_weight=1" that causes the tabs to sit at the bottom. http://snipplr.com/view/55565/android--tabs-on-the-bottom/